# JDBC: DriverManager.getConnection(url) not reading user/password

Tags: mysql, url, authentication, jdbc

I'm trying to open a connection to a db via the DriverManager. When I use the getConnection(url, properties) function it works fine, however when I try to append the username and password (something like `jdbc:mysql:address;user=user;password=password`) to the url and call `getConnection(url)` I get the following error

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db_aux_linux64_mysql;user=user;password=password'
```

So while it was able to find the db, it is trying to pass in an empty string as the user argument (and probably the password as well) for some reason. Any ideas on why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong url syntax, try this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname?user=user&password=password");
```

**Note**: Don't forget to add your database name after your hostname -- the error message you are getting is indicating that the jdbc driver is looking for a database that is literally named *"db_aux_linux64_mysql;user=user;password=password"*.

Alternatively, you can just use the `DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass)` as suggested in the comments, then you don't need to remember the url syntax for your jdbc driver (and your code will be more portable since each jdbc driver is subject to having different url syntax).

Source: [Mysql doc seciton 6.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)